# Erro MYSQL #1193 - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages'

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me with this error. From several searches on the Net I have not found a solution. I'm using version 7.0.10 of PHP and when I try to log in to phpMyAdmin, the following message appears:

> Erro
>
> Comando SQL: Edita Edita
>
> SET lc_messages = 'pt_PT';
>
> Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação
> #1193 - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages'

One other detail is I have installed Workbench version 6 and MySQL 5.1.

Answer (score 2):

`SET lc_messages = ...` doesn't work in MySQL Server 5.1.  This variable was introduced in 5.5.

> Before MySQL 5.5, the `lc_messages_dir` and `lc_messages` system variables were unavailable.
>
> To start mysqld with a particular language for error messages, the `--language` or `-L` option were used. The option value can be a language name or the full path to the error message file.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-message-language.html